# Combine a SPLIT formula with a formula that chooses N unique words from the SPLIT outcome

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got a sentence which I SPLIT into words without the punctuation. Next I want to choose three random, but unique words from that split. I use the formula as seen in cell I2. Is it possible to combine both the SPLIT formula and the other formula into one (big) formula?

[image]

SPLIT formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A2," "),"[,.?!]",""))
```

Formula to choose three random unique words:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN( 
ROW(B2:G2)&"×"&RANDARRAY(ROWS(B2:G2), COLUMNS(B2:G2))&"×"&B2:G2), "×"),
"select max(Col3) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),
 "offset 1", 0),,9^9)), " "), 9^9, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want to get 3 random unique words from a string.
in what follows i am going to demonstrate how get *truly* random words when the sheet is modified plus handling exceptions, ponctuation and more, like this take a look at [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qBoDlKPKMSykbh-iqKhYPkMgB2KMZ56rczx8avJgABM/edit?usp=sharing).

**Solution:**

Notes:

- This solution handels punctuation notice the highlighted characters with yellow.
- To get N unique random words just replace [n] of [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) Function with a cell refrence.

[image: Top n unique random words]

> Paste this formula in `B2`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2="",,JOIN(" ,",TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORTN({RANDARRAY(COUNTA(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[[:punct:]]",""))," ")))),TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[[:punct:]]",""))," ")))},3,,1,RANDBETWEEN(0,1))," Select Col2 ")))))
```

**Explanation:** *Pending...*

1 - We need [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)([`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)([`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en)([`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)`(A2,"[[:punct:]]",""))," "))` to rplace punctuation with nothing `""` and [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) spaces in start, tailing and additional spaces, [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) the string with `" "` as a delimiter, and then get the [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en) columns resulted from [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en), which is
 `He|is|cunning|as|a|fox` and  [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) the output like this [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)([`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)(`[Output]`)
to join it with random numbers column later.

2 - we need an Array [`{}`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) that contain `He|is|cunning|as|a|fox` and column with random numbers , like this `{` [`RANDARRAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9211904?hl=en) `, He|is|cunning|as|a|fox }`.

To get the column with random numbers: `RANDARRAY(COUNTA(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[[:punct:]]",""))," "))))`

 [`RANDARRAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9211904?hl=en) takes `[columns]` set to `1` and [rows] set to `COUNTA(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"[[:punct:]]",""))," ")))`  which is the [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en)`( He|is|cunning|as|a|fox )`

3 - Now we have to [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624?hl=en) the output with [n] set to `3` meaning 3 words in this case
**"to get N unique random words"** just replace [n] with a cell refrence.
[sort_column] set to `1` the column of random number and [is_ascending] set to [`RANDBETWEEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093507?hl=en)`(0,1)` to get either `0` or `1`, [is_ascending] `0` means Flase it sort's Descending , `1` means True sort ascending.

4 - [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) " Select Col2 ", the randomized column of words.

5 - [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) the column.

6 - [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) with `" ,"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only downside I see with this one is that the formula chooses between two sets of three random words. It seems to be either "He ,is ,cunning" or "fox ,a , as". I'm going to use the [[:punct:]] in my regexreplace. Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: @Jelmer405 it's fixed now  take a look.

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a while I came across the use of array_constrain to pick a fixed number of results and sort with randarray to randomize the outcome.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
transpose(SORT(transpose(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A2," "),"[,.?!]",""))),
randarray(COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(A2," "),"[,.?!]","")))),true))
,1,3)
```

If anyone happens to have a better solution to this, I would gladly see a response.